# Can I use reverse iterator as ForwardIt?

Tags: c++, iterator, reverse-iterator

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785268/heap-buffer-overflow-when-using-stdrotate).
[std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) is defined the following way:

```
template< class ForwardIt >
constexpr ForwardIt rotate( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt n_first, ForwardIt last );
```

Looking at the name `ForwardIt`, it expects forward iterator.

**Question**: assuming that my initial collection supports forward iterator (e.g. `vector`), can I use **reverse iterators** here? Why/why not?

Looking at, for example, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/, I don't understand if what is returned be considered a forward iterator. Do I have to guarantee that reverse iterator satisfies [forward iterator's](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ForwardIterator/) properties? In this case, how can I check that it's true? [vector::rbegin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/) documentation doesn't mention if it's the case.

Comment: Not the answer, but cplusplus.com is not the best source. The page you linked is somewhat outdated compared to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements for `reverse_iterator` are given in [reverse.iter.requirements](https://eel.is/c++draft/reverse.iter.requirements#1):

> The template parameter Iterator shall either meet the requirements of a Cpp17BidirectionalIterator ([bidirectional.iterators]) or model bidirectional_­iterator ([iterator.concept.bidir]).

and the requirements for [iterator.concept.bidir](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.bidir#1):

> The bidirectional_­iterator concept adds the ability to move an iterator backward as well as forward.

So yes, a `reverse_iterator` can be used as a `forward_iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `iterator_category` member typedef. Iterators report their category by setting it to the appropriate tag.

> [ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator ]
>
> `iterator_category` — If `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category` models `std::derived_from<std::random_access_iterator_tag>`, this is `std::random_access_iterator_tag`. Otherwise, this is `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category` unchanged.

Given that the original iterator must be at least bidirectional (see link), it means that the resulting iterator is either random-access (if the original iterator is at least random-access), or bidirectional (otherwise).

(`std::derived_from` is used here because category A inherits from category B when A is a subset of B, meaning the requirements of A are a superset of the requirements of B. The only thing that inherits from `random_access_iterator_tag` is `contiguous_iterator_tag`.)